# My directive controller function isn't being triggered on ng-click. Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

my directive controller `$scope.closeSpinner` function isn't being triggered when button `ng-click="closeSpinner()"` is clicked on the directive template.

**AddUsers.Html**

```
<div spinner spinneron="playerSearchSpinnerOn"> </div>
```

**Directive**

```
monopolyMenuModule.directive('spinner', ['spinObj', function (spinObj) {
    return {

        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            spinneron: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope.$watch('spinneron', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue != oldValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        // load spinner, create a model dialog, with a cancel button.
                        var spinner = spinObj.spin();
                        var element = angular.element(".modal-content");
                        element.append(spinner.el);
                        $("#spinnerDialog").modal('show')
                    }
                    else if (newValue == false) {
                        // close spinner called.
                        spinObj(false);
                    }
                }
            });

        },
        controller: function($scope)
        {
            $scope.closeSpinner = function () {
                $scope.spinneron = false;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: '/Js/MonopolyMenu/model.html'
    }
}]);
```

Template Html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="spinnerDialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="closeSpinner()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you using you directive? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to help is if you create a Plunker or Fiddle as it isn't obvious from your samples what could be the problem.

Comment: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GQAm8x?p=info

Answer (score 2):

Based on the provided Plunkr, it seems to be working just fine. You should make sure your file paths are setup correctly to the template within the directive. Perform a test that it is being called with a console.log or $log.log call (as I have done in the plunk). Also, feel free to add the spinObject code to the provided Plunk.

Comment: Yeh, it works on mine also. I just had to clear the cache, and viola.. sorry for the post.